# How to add import-packages from a specific bundle version in OSGi

Tags: java, osgi, aem, sling

My project has two OSGi bundles (A and B) which need to use different versions of `javax.activation` — A requires version 1.1.0, while B requires 1.1.1.

By default in AEM 5.6.1, there is a bundle already installed which exports version 1.1.1, which bundle A is using. In order to make it use 1.1.0 instaed, I used boot delegation to get the javax.activation from the JRE 7 for the system bundle which is 1.1.0. I am setting this using sling.properties file in AEM 5.6.1.

If I give a version for javax.activation greater than 1.1.1 in this sling.properties file, both A and B are using the system version (even though version of import-packages is specified in the `manifest.mf` file); but if I give a version less than 1.1.1, both bundles use the version provided by AEM.

How can I configure my bundles so as to use different versions of javax.activation for Bundle A from Bundle B?

Comment: could you provide your Import-Package declaration from your manifest?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use exactly 1.1.0 version in bundle A, than you should specify it in A's manifest file:

```
Import-Package: javax.activation;version="[1.1.0,1.1.0]"
```

For bundle B manifest will be:

```
Import-Package: javax.activation;version="[1.1.1,1.1.1]"
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be downright difficult due to the OSGI bundle resolution rules.  Check out this article--I found it to be a good explanation of the various rules that apply.  Specifically, check out the `uses` directive:
http://www.christianposta.com/blog/?p=241

Life will be much simpler if there is a way for both to use the the same version (but I know that may not always be possible).

This is from the article above:

> For every Import-Package package declaration, there must be a
>   corresponding Export-Package with the same package
>
> Bundles can also attach other attributes to the packages it imports or
>   exports. What if we added a version attribute to our example:
>
> Bundle-Name: Bundle A Import-Package: org.apache.foo;version="1.2.0"
>
> This means, Bundle A has a dependency on package org.apache.foo with a
>   minimum version of 1.2.0. Yes, you read correctly. Although with OSGI
>   you can specify a range of versions, if you don’t specify a range but
>   rather use a fixed version, it will result in a meaning of “a minimum”
>   of the fixed value. If there is a higher version for that same
>   package, the higher version will be used. So bundle A will not resolve
>   correctly unless there is a corresponding bundle B that exports the
>   required package:
>
> Bundle-Name: Bundle B Export-Package: org.apache.foo;version="1.2.0"
>
> Note that the reverse is not true… If Bundle B exported version 1.2.0,
>   Bundle A is not required to specify a version 1.2.0. It can use this
>   import and resolve just fine:
>
> Bundle-Name: Bundle A Import-Package: org.apache.foo
>
> This is because imports declare the versions they need. An exported
>   version does not specify anything an importing bundle must use (which
>   holds for any attributes, not just version). Import-Package dictates
>   exactly what version (or attribute) it needs, and a corresponding
>   Export-Package with the same attribute must exist
>
> What happens if you have a scenario where Bundle A imports a package
>   and it specifies a version that is provided by two bundles:
>
> Bundle-Name: Bundle A Import-Package: org.apache.foo;version="1.2.0"
>
> Bundle-Name: Bundle B Export-Package: org.apache.foo;version="1.2.0"
>
> Bundle-Name: Bundle C Export-Package: org.apache.foo;version="1.2.0"
>
> Which one bundle does Bundle A use? The answer is it depends on which
>   bundle (B or C) was installed first. Bundles installed first are used
>   to satisfy a dependency when multiple packages with the same version
>   are found
>
> Things can get a little more complicated when hot deploying bundles
>   after some have already been resolved. What if you install Bundle B
>   first, then try to install Bundle A and the following Bundle D
>   together:
>
> Bundle-Name: Bundle D Export-Package: org.apache.foo;version="1.3.0"
>
> As we saw from above, the version declaration in Bundle A (1.2.0)
>   means a minimum version of 1.2.0; so if a higher version was available
>   then it would select that (version 1.3.0 from Bundle D in this case).
>   However, that brings us to another temporal rule for the bundle
>   resolution: Bundles that have already been resolved have a higher
>   precedence that those not resolved
>
> The reason for this is the OSGI framework tends to favor reusability
>   for a given bundle. If it’s resolved, and new bundles need it, then it
>   won’t try to have many other versions of the same package if it
>   doesn’t need to. Bundle “uses” directive
>
> The above rules for bundle resolution are still not enough and the
>   wrong class could still be used at runtime resulting in a class-cast
>   exception or similar. Can you see what could be missing?
>
> What if we had this scenario. Bundle A exports a package,
>   org.apache.foo, that contains a class, FooClass. FooClass has a method
>   that returns an object of type BarClass, but BarClass is not defined
>   in the bundle’s class space, it’s imported like this:
>
> 1 2 3      public class FooClass {
>       public BarClass execute(){ ... } }
>
> Bundle-Name: Bundle A Import-Package: org.apache.bar;version="3.6.0"
>   Export-Package: org.apache.foo;version="1.2.0"
>
> So far everything is fine as long as there is another bundle that
>   properly exports org.apache.bar with the correct version.
>
> Bundle-Name: Bundle B Export-Package: org.apache.bar;version="3.6.0"
>
> These two bundles will resolve fine. Now, if we install two more
>   bundles, Bundle C and Bundle D that look like this:
>
> Bundle-Name: Bundle C Import-Package: org.apache.foo;version="1.2.0",
>   org.apache.bar;version="4.0.0"
>
> Bundle-Name: Bundle D Export-Package: org.apache.bar;version="4.0.0"
>
> We can see that Bundle C imports a package, org.apache.foo from Bundle
>   A. Bundle C can try to use FooClass from org.apache.foo, but when it
>   gets the return value, a type of BarClass, what will happen? Bundle A
>   expects to use version 3.6.0 of BarClass, but bundle C is using
>   version 4.0.0. So the classes used are not consistent within bundles
>   at runtime (i.e., you could experience some type of mismatch or class
>   cast exception), but everything will still resolve just fine at deploy
>   time following the rules from above. What we need is to tell anyone
>   that imports org.apache.foo that we use classes from a specific
>   version of org.apache.bar, and if you want to use org.apache.foo you
>   must use the same version that we import. That’s exactly what the uses
>   directive does. Let’s change bundle A to specify exactly that:
>
> Bundle-Name: Bundle A Import-Package: org.apache.bar;version="3.6.0"
>   Export-Package: org.apache.foo;version="1.2.0"";uses:=org.apache.bar
>
> Given the new configuration for Bundle A, the bundles would not
>   resolve correctly from above. Bundle C could not resolve, because it
>   imports org.apache.foo but the “uses” constraint on Bundle A specifies
>   that C must use the same version that A does (3.6.0) for
>   org.apache.bar, otherwise the bundle will not resolve when trying to
>   deploy. The solution to this is change the version in Bundle C for
>   org.apache.bar to be 3.6.0.